# Dart copy a parent directory to another directory

Tags: dart

Using dart, how can I search each child directory to see if it has a .txt file. Then if it does copy the parent directory to another directory input in the function.

**Sudo code**
search_directory  = x
to_directorys = y
for dir in search_directory  :
if dir has a txt file:
move dir to to_directorys

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: To elaborate on Chris's comment, this question has too large a scope. What exactly do you need to know? How to list a directory? How to iterate over a directory listing? How to search for a matching pattern in a list of file names? etc.

Comment: Also: Consider using generative AI tools to help with these sorts of large questions. ChatGPT handles this one quite well.